# Error when using the null-propagating / null-conditional operator

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, null-propagation-operator

I am running a .NET 4.5 project in VS 2013. Why is the following code in error?

```
var w = Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as System.Web.HttpContextWrapper;
string IP = w?.Request.UserHostAddress; //fail to compile
```

I found this code on this [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator.aspx).

Answer (score 17):

That is a new feature available in C# 6 and newer versions. It is called the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators).

In order to use C# 6 you should download Visual Studio 2015 or a newer version, since the extension for Visual Studio 2013 isn't supported any more (see [here](http://roslyn.codeplex.com)).

Comment: Well, a note from Mads: http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/552378#post1291188 Beyond that... emails :)

Comment: @Old: need more help?